# Having many small executable C# scripts in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, scripting

I'd like to have something like a single "Scripts" project which I would populate with many smaller C# programs, all individually runnable. Ideally, I'd be able to run any one of them via a right-click menu.

Is something like this possible?

If not, what the closest I can get to it?

As a specific use case: I have a small C# program that populates my database. I run it every now and then during development, but it feels wrong to have it as its own project. It's also sufficiently complex that I wouldn't want to translate it to SQL.

Comment: Look at [LINQPad](https://www.linqpad.net/).

Comment: @Blorgbeard Thanks, that looks very interesting. That said, I'd still like to stay within VS if at all possible: I'm sharing the project with other people and would not want them to have to install additional software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to have unit test for each script, that way you can easily choose which one to run using visual studio.

`ReSharper` has a nice unit test runner, that makes it easy to `run selected` or `all` unit test with one click from within visual studio.

[image: VS 2013 Unit Test resharper]

If you do not have `ReSharper` have a look at :  [NUnit Test Adapter Free](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6ab922d0-21c0-4f06-ab5f-4ecd1fe7175d)

Comment: Clever, although having unit tests that mess with your working database is annoying when you Run All and don't realise your data will be reset.

Answer (score 1):

You can use my [Visual Commander](https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/) extension to create and run small C# scripts as commands within Visual Studio.

Comment: This looks great! I'll try it out.